# Can I force gcc to detect ALL undefined behavior?

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior

Is there a way to force gcc to detect all undefined behavior? I want it to detect both things that can be discovered at compile time and runtime. I know that UB is useful both for making it simpler to create the compilers and to allow the compiler to optimize the code. The latter is not relevant when you're debugging, and the need of lightweight compilers is not as big as it was 1972. Furthermore, gcc is a very mature compiler at this point, and if this was possible, it would bake debugging so much easier.

I know that `-Wformat` will yield a warning for `printf("%d", 42)` and for uninitialized variables. The parameter `-Warray-bounds` *might* catch when you try to access memory outside an array, although I needed to put some work in constructing code that actually yielded a warning. I also know that some runtime errors can be detected with `-fstack-protector-all`.

So my question is simply this. Is there a way to *guarantee* that all UB gets detected, either at compilation if possible, but at the very latest when it happens in runtime?

Comment: No but you can detect more kinds of UB at run time by using sanitizers (e.g. `-fsanitize=undefined`).

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible. Detecting undefined behavior can literally require solving the halting problem; for example, quoting [C11 6.8.5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5p6):

> 6 An iteration statement whose controlling expression is not a constant expression, that performs no input/output operations, does not access volatile objects, and performs no synchronization or atomic operations in its body, controlling expression, or (in the case of a for statement) its expression-3, may be assumed by the implementation to terminate.

C is not designed to make error detection easy.

Comment: Computers are finite, so no halting problem needs to be involved, just a very big cache of memory states.

Comment: @n.m.: We could get into a very long comment thread about issues like where you're going to put that cache (in memory?), tortoise-and-hare cycle detection, whether it still counts if you're not going to detect the UB before the heat death of the universe, whether it counts as UB if the loop would have finished normally without the extra memory consumption of the UB detection apparatus, etc., but let's just skip all that and say that detecting this is not practically feasible (and there's plenty of other UB that's infeasible to detect beyond just this).

Comment: *where you're going to put that cache* In memory of course. Memory available for the implementation is not the same as memory available for the program. *not going to detect the UB before the heat death of the universe* The standard does not require the loop to terminate before the heat death of the universe either. *detecting this is not practically feasible* I won't argue with that. *there's plenty of other UB that's infeasible to detect* I would in fact argue with that. Most other UB is feasible to detect with some constant performance sacrifice factor.

Comment: @n.m.: Well, if you want to have this conversation, let's [head to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192099/room-for-user2357112-and-n-m) preemptively instead of having a 20-reply comment thread that gets mod-nuked.

Answer (score 2):

That's in principle impossible. Consider that some UB can depend on runtime data in very complex ways.

If you ask your user to input a value at runtime and then use that value as a pointer (or to compute a pointer) which you dereference and write through, how do you detect the write will cause UB or not? You can check the process image and see if the write will cause a segfault right away, but if it doesn't how do you detect that the write wasn't in a place that will cause a butterfly effect that will ultimately lead to a segfault or execution of unintended code?

It doesn't have to be about pointers either. You can parse faster if you assume all input is well formed (no error checking on malformed input), but if you then parse a malformed file, anything can happen just as with the pointer example.

Comment: Not sure the file example is what the OP is getting at, you can parse something nonsensical in Java, Javascript, etc.?

Comment: @FireLancer Well, language parsers generally don't go undefined on malformed input, but if you have a huge data file you need to parse and you're 100% sure it's well formed, you can write a faster parser if utilize that knowledge.

Comment: It is possible to detect all UB (at run time), just prohibitively expensive.

Comment: @PSkocik Maybe we are thinking from different points, I was thinking like `x = binaryReader.readInt();` and not range checking, or checking requirements like `x >= y`, and maybe you get some bad data, maybe it was actually a float or something. Java doesn't save a program from reading junk from external sources, and what happens to the data after it is read is the first part?

Comment: @n.m. Well,  bounds checking, overflow checking and other locally detectable instances of UB wouldn't be that hard, but you'd also need to get lifetimes and reinterpretations under control and that would be quite difficult with the language as it is (separate compilation and all).

Comment: @n.m. I believe `valgrind` can catch most of the regular pointer errors. It would be interesting to see an example that is impossible, and if languages like .NET/Java prevent such a construct, or just "define it". The OP was talking about debugging/debug builds, not production, so being many times slower would be OK for that purpose? I am thinking that interactions with any so/DLL could be a case, as well as some more complex pointer manipulation?

Comment: @FireLancer pointer errors are not the only kind of UB out there, and valgrind only catches some of them. The simplest example that comes to mind is out of bounds access in a 2D array. `int a[2][2]; a[0][2] = 42;` is UB but valgrind won't catch it.

Comment: @PSkocik Separate compilation is not mandatory. You basically need tagged memory.

Comment: One could construct an implementation which defines the behavior of all possible programs, and specifies that it will trap on any attempt to process actions whose behavior could not be meaningfully specified otherwise.  Such implementations could be extremely useful when running untrustworthy code.  While the Standard is written in such a way, however, that it would be neither practical nor useful to trap all code whose behavior is not mandated by the Standard, defining more behaviors would make it practical to trap any behaviors outside the expanded set.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this example (assume we have some arbitrary-precision `BigInteger` class and a function `random_big_int` that returns the positive integer n with probability `1/2^n`)

```cpp
void compute_collatz(BigInteger x) {
    while (x != 1) {
        if (x % 2) {
            x = 3*x + 1;
        } else {
            x = x / 2;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Terminated successfully!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    BigInteger x = random_big_int();
    compute_collatz(x);
}
```

If the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is false, this may enter a side-effect-free infinite loop (if a random integer is picked for which the conjecture is false), which is undefined behavior.

So, in order to tell whether this can invoke UB, the compiler would need to know whether the Collatz conjecture is true, which is an open problem in mathematics.