# Are there undefined behaviors that escape fsanitize in clang/gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, undefined-behavior, address-sanitizer

Question about undefined behavior in C/C++: if I compile a program, say, `file.c`, with:

```
clang/gcc -g -fsanitize=address,undefined,signed-integer-overflow -fno-sanitize-recover=all file.c
```

And the program runs and terminates normally, can I assume that this program did not incur in any undefined behavior during that execution? If that is not the case, and an undefined behavior is still possible, could you give me a counter example? And, is there a way to catch this undefined behavior? Perhaps using [RV-Match](https://runtimeverification.com/match/)?

Comment: “Undefined behavior” as the C standard defines it includes calling operating system routines. The sanitize features are not going to warn you about those because they are consider perfectly normal.

Comment: Scanning the summary of undefined behaviors in C 2018 J.2, I suspect the general compiler behavior and the sanitize features would not warn you about all instances of “The execution of a program contains a data race (5.1.2.4),” all instances of “An object is referred to outside of its lifetime (6.2.4)” (and related behaviors, such as a pointer to it), “Two declarations of the same object or function specify types that are not compatible (6.2.7),” “A pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type (6.3.2.3),” …

Comment: Related: [Can I force gcc to detect ALL undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55759044/6865932)

Comment: … “A side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the same scalar object (6.5),“ “For a call to a function without a function prototype in scope, the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters (6.5.2.2)” (and similar function call issues), “An object is assigned to an inexactly overlapping object or to an exactly overlapping object with incompatible type (6.5.16.1),” “A restrict-qualified pointer is assigned a value based on another restricted pointer… (6.7.3.1),” …

Comment: … “A function declared with a `_Noreturn` function specifier returns to its caller (6.7.4),” “The `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller (6.9.1),” and more.

Comment: Here you go - a program with UB which "runs and terminates normally": https://godbolt.org/z/vnv7q3jqM .Of course, it depends on your expectations of "normally".

Comment: Almost by definition, a compiler cannot catch all instances of undefined behavior.  It's great that compilers are trying harder to these days, and `-fsanitize=undefined` is particularly welcome, but it's never going to be able to catch, for example, `x = (*p)++ + (*q)++` where `p` happens to equal `q`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Thank you very much! That was exactly the kind of program that I was looking for. I could catch that UB using kcc. It reported: "_Unsequenced side effect on scalar object with side effect of same object_".

Answer (score 3):

> Are there undefined behaviors that escape fsanitize in clang/gcc?

Yes, of course.

> can I assume that this program did not incur in any undefined behavior during that execution?

No.

> If that is not the case, and an undefined behavior is still possible, could you give me a counter example?

There are many, many, many, many such examples. Dunno, for example this idea:

```
int __; int main() { return 0; }
```

Compiles cleanly on gcc12.1 and clang14.0 with `-fsanitize=address,undefined,signed-integer-overflow -fno-sanitize-recover=all --pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ansi`. Yet, contains an identifier that starts with two underscores, which is undefined behavior.

> is there a way to catch this undefined behavior?

I would say it is not proven if it is possible or not to catch all possible undefined behaviors.

Comment: "I would say it is not proven if it is possible or not to catch all possible undefined behaviors." I would represent [it is proven you cannot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Comment: @kopecs: It would be possible to determine whether any *particular execution* of a CompCertC program invoked Undefined Behavior.  Such questions are not answerable for any version of the C Standard, however, is the fact that the Standards were not written to unambiguously categorize each individual action of a program as either having defined behavior or invoking Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thank you guys! I don't think that the problem fits into the framework of Rice's Theorem though: the program terminates; hence, we can observe its execution trace. Perhaps, the problem would be that the Standard contains ambiguities. But there are attempts to fully formalize it. Take, for instance, a look into "Defining the undefinedness of C", by Hathhorn et al. That paper gave origin to kcc, which catches lots of undefined behaviors. But it did not catch the double underscore example.

Comment: @FernandoMagnoQuintaoPereira: Not only is the Standard ambiguous, but it is impossible to interpret it consistently in a manner that does not either classify as UB some actions it was obviously intended to define, or characterize as defined some actions that some compiler writers regard as Undefined Behavior.  This wouldn't be a problem if compiler writers gave priority to behavioral specifications absent a compelling reason to do otherwise, but unfortunately some compiler treat the fact that the Standard can be viewed as characterizing an action as UB as trumping everything else.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard was never written to unambiguously partition all program executions into those which exhibit Undefined Behavior and those which do not.  No tool could possibly identify all of the program executions that an implementation might conceivably process nonsensically, without also flagging many program executions which all practical implementations would in fact process consistently.

This is especially true many situations involving `restrict`.  Whether constructs have defined behavior or not will often depend upon whether changing some pointer Q so it points to a copy of the same data would change the value produced by evaluating some other pointer expression P.  While there are times when this definition will sensibly recognize some pointer P as being unambiguously based upon Q, and there are times when it will sensibly recognize some pointer P as unambiguously not based upon Q, there are times when it does neither.  The question of whether a program's behavior is defined in such circumstances may be essentially unanswerable, and thus an implementation could not plausibly be expected to answer it.